# How do I use Excel's new Filter formula to return a unique value as one would with the "match type" input?

Tags: excel, filter, match

I'm having some trouble retrieving only a single data point, where the match function would usually return an "exact match or next largest value" for match_type = -1 in MATCH(lookup_value,lookup_range,[match_type]), the filter function spills out all the options "smaller than" the selected figure as outlined in blue below.

For the selected parameters (cells with blue fill), the desired output is 30.

Is there anyway to do this whilst still using the array configuration?

[image: Illustration]

Comment: The whole point of FILTER is to return all matching records. Sounds like you want a simple LOOKUP formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use and INDEX MATCH and Filter both the search range and the output range:

```
=INDEX(FILTER(C:C,A:A=F2),MATCH(F3,FILTER(B:B,A:A=F2),1))
```

[image]

Or Vlookup:

```
=VLOOKUP(F3,FILTER(B:C,A:A=F2),2,TRUE)
```

[image]

---

Without the access to FILTER() use AGGREGATE:

```
 =INDEX(C:C,AGGREGATE(14,7,ROW($C$2:$C$10)/(($A$2:$A$10=F2)*($B$2:$B$10<=F3)),1))
```

[image]